# is passport required when using JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, express-jwt

Very basic question but probably I miss something very big in the big picture.
I cannot figure out whether passport.js is needed or not when using JWT auth. Most examples have it but I fail to see the need.

In my app, there is a /login route and once the user authenticates successfully ( local auth, I check user, a hash pair in the database) I create a token with user id in it, set an expiry, sign it and send it back as the cookie in the response. Then I check the req cookies, decrypt and if they contain user id and not expired, I consider the request authenticated. (also traffic is https only if it changes anything)

Am I doing something wrong here as I don't have passport etc. in the process?

Comment: No, [JWT (RFC 7519)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519) is a standard.  `passport.js` is an implementation that uses JWT.  It isn't required.

Comment: @zero298, you should put your comment as answer. It deserves to be the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [JWT (RFC 7519)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) is a standard. **passport.js** is an implementation that uses JWT. It is not required.